Can the plane be partitioned into tripods?
I recently was surprised to learn that the plane can be partitioned into closed segments (see the paper "Covering a sphere with congruent great-circle arcs" by Conway and Croft for the construction).
This led me to wonder about which other spaces the plane can be partitioned into. Specifically, I've found myself most interested in whether the plane can be partitioned into tripods (the wedge sum of three copies of $[0,1]$ each with basepoint $0$)?
Intuitively it feels like it is not possible to even fit uncountably many disjoint tripods into the plane. So,

Can uncountably many disjoint tripods fit in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
If the answer to $1$ is affirmitive, can $\mathbb{R}^2$ be partitioned into tripods (i.e. can $\mathbb{R}^2 = \bigsqcup_{\alpha\in A}T_\alpha$ where each $T_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to a tripod)?

The tripods I'm considering are topological, they don't need to be congruent in the partition.

Could you explain what exactly you mean by "partition"? Do you take a certain subset of the plane and try to partition the plane (as a set) into shifted and rotated copies of that set? Do you allow scaling? Also, in this case, is the tripod three line segments joined at the origin separated by equal angles, i.e. a three-pronged asterisk shape? Wedge sum of three copies of $[0, 1]$ does not say anything about the angles.

I mean "Can the plane be written as a disjoint union of spaces each of which is homeomorphic to a tripod?" As I mentioned at the bottom, I am only concerned with topological tripods, I impose no geometric constraints.

This is not possible, for the following reason.
First, each individual tripod (also known as a triod) is nowhere dense in the plane.
Next, by applying the the Baire category theorem, it follows that any covering of the plane with tripods must consist of uncountably many tripods.
However, any set of pairwise disjoint tripods in the plane must be countable. This is an old topological chestnut. I found a proof (and the origin of the problem) in this mathoverlow answer. And that link contains, in turn, a link to the original proof by R. L. Moore whose uses the term triod.

As you suspect, you cannot fit uncountably many tripods into the plane.
Here's a sketch of one way to prove this. Given a tripod (= a subset of the plane homeomorphic to the union of the three closed line segments connecting the origin with $(1,0), (0,1)$, and $(1,1)$ respectively) $T$, let $\epsilon_T$ be some positive rational such that the circle $C$ with radius $\epsilon_T$ and center the "root" of $T$ intersects $T$ in at least one point of each "leg" of $T$. Then, let $\theta_T$ be the angle of the shortest arc in $C$ which meets each "leg" of $T$. Finally, given a collection of disjoint tripods in the plane $\mathcal{T}$ and a rational $q>0$, let $[q]_\mathcal{T}$ be the set of all tripods $T$ in $\mathcal{T}$ with both $\theta_T$ and $\epsilon_T$ greater than $q$.
It's not hard to show that for each $q\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ the set $[q]_\mathcal{T}$ must be countable. But then $\mathcal{T}$ itself must be countable, since $\mathcal{T}=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}}[q]_\mathcal{T}$.

Incidentally, it turns out that "shapes" (= compact sets in the plane) satisfy a reasonable dichotomy in this case. Basically, for every shape, either we can pack continuum-many "copies" of that shape into the plane, or we can only ever pack countably many "copies." See this old MO question of mine; to the best of my knowledge, the situation for general closed sets (let alone Borel sets) is still open, but I suspect that Ashutosh's argument can be made to extend to these too.
